# HTML/CSS Define a selection of characters' styling via CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I define a selection of characters' styling via CSS?

For example, I have this code in which the *G* is supposed to have a special font/size and the *uru* is supposed to be normally styled.

```
<font style="font-family: BlessedDay; font-size: 180px;">G</font>uru
```

The above works but I am assuming is not good practice. How can I do this with a CSS class definition?

Comment: It's not every day that you see `<font style="...">` being used, let alone acknowledged as not being good practice.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) lists it as obsolete in HTML5 (deprecated in HTML 4.01).  So it _shouldn't_ be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar, but use SPANS:

```
<span class="biggie">G</span>uru
```

CSS:

```
.biggie {
  font-family: BlessedDay;
  font-size: 180px;  
}
```

Note that "BlessedDay" does not seem to be a freely available webfont.

Comment: Thank you; this is the answer I'm looking for!

And yes I'm aware of that, I have declared the font successfully in my CSS. :)

Comment: Apart from formal issues (some specifications frown upon `font`), `span` offers no benefits over `font`. In factm `span` is semantically empty, whereas `font` says that some font settings are made. But using a `class` instead of `style` has tangible benefits: if you need the same styling elsewhere, you don’t need to repeat the CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use the pseudo selector [`first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter). Note: This can not be used on inline elements, which is why I used a `p` instead of `span`.

HTML

```
<p class="guru">Guru</p>
```

CSS

```
.guru:first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: BlessedDay;
}
```

**[DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kscjx/1/)**

EDIT: Assuming I was downvoted because I didn't use a class. Fixed to reflect OP's requirements:

> How can I do this with a CSS class definition?

Comment: Really cool trick although I didn't want to use paragraphs at all! Thanks though, another trick for the books!

Comment: If it's the only thing on your page, you could do it with no spans, divs, or anything by using `first-letter` :). http://jsfiddle.net/TxMEX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<span class="c1">G</span>uru

<style>
 .c1 {
  font-family: BlessedDay;
  font-size: 180px;
 }
</style>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eZar7/)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different answer, and I'd recommend using Diodeus' answer for cross-browser reasons, but if you're only doing it to the [first letter](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) you could also mark up as:

```
<p class="big">Guru lorem ipsum</p>
```

CSS:

```
.big:first-letter { font-family: BlessedDay; font-size:180px; }
```

Comment: I knew of using paragraph with class but didn't want to add boilerplate code to remove indentation/whitespace. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jire if you're applying it to every paragraph you don't need the class, I just added it for argument's sake

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/StacyAwwburn/R3hTq/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="adoptabledogs">
<p>Max</p>
<p>Marbles</p>
<p>Mary</p>
<p>Moe</p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.adoptabledogs {
font-family: BlessedDay, sans-serif;
font-size: 45px;
color: green;
}
```

Comment: I knew of using division tag but didn't want to (just as using the paragraph tag) restyle with boilerplate to match my desired result. Thanks for your effort, though!

Comment: I don't know how this answers the OP's question at all... This applies styles to every child element of `.adoptabledogs`.